# Is there a way to do a conditional $lookup in mongo - nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, group-by, lookup

In our streaming application we have different collections (seasons, contents, episodes) in which we arrange our videos. At the moment the default object of a content returned is like
`content: { ... seasons: [ ... episodes: [...] ] }`

We want to add another collection named "topics" to divide the episodes in a season so it should be like
`content: { ... seasons: [ ... topics: [ ... episodes: [...] ] ] }`

The "topic" is optional, so I need a way to do a lookup (or something similar) with a condition.
If I do something like this

```
  [ { $match: { _id: Types.ObjectId(id) } }, { $lookup: { from: 'seasons', let: { 'content': '$_id' },      
    pipeline: [
            { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$content", "$$content"] }, deleted: { $ne: true } } },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: 'topics',
                let: { 'season': '$_id' },
    
                pipeline: [
                  { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$season", "$$season"] }, deleted: { $ne: true }} },
                  {
                    $lookup: {
                      from: 'episodes',
                      pipeline: [
                        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$season", "$$season"] }, deleted: { $ne: true }} },
                      ],
                      as: 'episodes',
                    }
                  }
                ],
                as: 'topics',
              }
            }
          ],
          as: 'seasons',
        }
      },
    ]
```

it works, but only if the episodes have a topic. How can I make it works when there is no topic?